# UITextView - Enable dictation alert disappears quickly

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I've text view. When keyboard is showing and I tap on dictation icon it shows Enable Dictation window and then disappears quickly on a device. On simulator it works on some and not on others. I'm not sure why it's happening. I've searched but can't find any single result with similar issue.

It's not just with text view, it also happens on search bar.

This issue doesn't happen on iPhone X device.

Any clue on why it's happening and how to fix it or what to look for?

I did a test and created a new VC in my app with only text view and it also doesn't work there. This confirms that this issue has nothing to do with anything in the code. May be it is to do with some project settings?

I also see following error:

```
[Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=221 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2832cf8a0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "(null)"}}
!!! _NSLayoutTreeGetBaselineOffsetForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when was using `AVAudioEngine` - when dictation starts the engine stops, and by starting it again (following the `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification`) I was interrupting the dictation. I had to pause the player when dictation starts:

```
textInputModeObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil,
    queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
        guard
            let self = self,
            self.textView.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage == "dictation"
            else { return }
        self.player.pause()
}
```

Comment: I don't use any AVAudioEngine in my app anywhere however I don't have Audio players as I play sound. I'm not sure if any of the sound related code can be affecting dictation?

Comment: I did a test and created a new VC with only text view and it also doesn't work there. This confirms that this issue has nothing to do with anything in the code. May be it is to do with project settings?

Comment: Have you tried adding new VC as a rootVC of your window? My case was related to audio player, and when I tried to reproduce it in the clean project the bug didn't appeared, that's how I know it was related not to the project settings but to my code. I've added the code I'm using to solve the problem

Comment: Just now I tried a new VC as root VC and still the same problem. My project is complex as it has voip. Dictation alert is disappearing even on those VCs where there is no audio related code. In AppDelegate.swift there is no audio play but it has CallKit audio related code. There is no other common code which is being executed on these VCs where dictation has issue. Not sure how to go from here?

Comment: Not sure. Check out if in new project it works fine. Try to remove all project files from your target to see if it's a project settings related bug, or one of you files has some code that's executed even with empty root vc.

Comment: It works on a new project. Thanks for help. I'll investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking if you have implemented speech framework in your code? If not try this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-convert-speech-to-text-using-sfspeechrecognizer

Comment: No, we don't need to implement speech framework or any other framework at all. Device will automatically handle dictation after you click on microphone icon.